# IndexOutofBounexception in search adapter onbind method?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I keep getting IndexOutofBoundsException from my onBind method in search adapter as soon as I start to search /filter my recyclerview list results. 
Here's the exception :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 0(offset:0).state:25 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{3247b3d VFED..... ......ID 0,0-1440,5550 #7f090216 app:id/search_guests_recycler_view}, adapter:com.myapp.ui.registervisitor.searchGuests.SearchGuestListAdapter@2433f32, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@68f5483, context:com.myapp.ui.registervisitor.searchGuests.SearchGuestActivity@843713
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5923)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1414)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:452)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:805)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:805)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
```

I tried a couple of articles online, but no luck. some of the articles that I tried are : [RecyclerView Adapter onBind method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55180115/recyclerview-adapter-onbind-method) and [RecyclerView: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220771/recyclerview-inconsistency-detected-invalid-item-position)

My adapter code for this issue is at : 
https://pastebin.com/VxsWWMiS

and corresponding activity code for filtering :

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                mSearchGuestListAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mSearchGuestListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                mSearchGuestListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mSearchGuestListAdapter.setFilter(newText);

                if(mSearchGuestListAdapter.getItemCount() == 0){


                    String sourceString = "No match found for <b>" + newText + "</b> ";
                    mNoMatchTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));
                } else {
                    mEmptyRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Happy to share any other details if needed. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Here's my entire activity code: https://pastebin.com/5qDN4yh9

This is the presenter class where the API is called : https://pastebin.com/YGiPGn8Z

This is the model class: https://pastebin.com/WCkPFnvU

This is a json sample : https://pastebin.com/82R1zBHP

Here's the xml code where recyclerview is called : https://pastebin.com/Z3QxPkSL "search_guests_recycler_view"

Comment: use an adapter that already implements `Filterable`, why to reinvent the wheel? for example, this is the complete, working `Filterable` adapter: https://pastebin.com/raw/LEena3pM

Comment: I do already use implements Filterable in my adapter

Comment: thats why i said: "why to reinvent the wheel?" do you want to implement the same code in every adapter you want to be filtered?

Comment: I don't have any other code that requires filtering, but since this seems to be working as expected for my filter needs, can you help figure out what i might be missing that could be causing the crash? I wondr if it's something as simple as adding notifydatasetchanged or updating the position of the item? tried a coupl of things but no luck

Comment: you dont set `filterResults.count` - but i am not 100% sure if this is the only bug in your custom `Filter`

Comment: where do I set that in my code? I can test it out if that works

Comment: in the same place you set `filterResults.values`

Comment: so it would be line filterResults.count = mSearchListFiltered.size?

Comment: `mSearchGuestListResponseListFiltered.size`

Comment: @pskink it still crashes with E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.dev, PID: 3195
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 15(offset:15).state:25 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{82e3b0b VFED..... ......ID 0,0-1080,4175 #7f090216 app:id/search_guests_recycler_view}, adapter:com.myapp.ui.registervisitor.searchGuests.SearchGuestListAdapter@72eade8, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@14cec01, context:com.myapp.ui.registervisitor.searchGuests.SearchGuestActivity@6928c4b

Comment: is there anything in my activity or recyclerview that could be causing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple considerations in your code that may cause that inconsistency in your adapter.

To understand how Filter class works you should note that, according to [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter):

> **Filtering operations** performed by calling filter(java.lang.CharSequence) or filter(java.lang.CharSequence, android.widget.Filter.FilterListener) **are performed asynchronously**. When these methods are called, a filtering request is posted in a request queue and processed later. Any call to one of these methods will cancel any previous non-executed filtering request.

---

### 1. Use a single instance of Filter

The Filter class performs a background task in which the `performFiltering()` method is called. To avoid overlapping filters while typing you should avoid using multiple instances of Filter. In your SearchGuestListAdapter class:

**Incorrect:**

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // WRONG: Return new instance of Filter every time getFilter() is called
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            // Perform filtering...
            return anything;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            // Update and Notify adapter...
        }
    };
}
```

**Instead replace with:**

```
private final Filter filter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        // Perform filtering...
        return anything;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        // Update and Notify adapter...
    }
};

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // CORRECT: Always use the same Filter instance.
    return this.filter;
}
```

---

### 2. You should not modify adapter variables in performFiltering()

`performFiltering()` method is executed in a background thread. Here you can do a long job, read data from a database, even make a webservice synchronous request if you need it.

But, if you alter the adapter list here you will cause inconsistency between RecyclerView is showing on the screen and the contents of the adapter list. Instead you must build a temporary list that you will return using FilterResults.

**Fix performFiltering() with the following structure:**

```
@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
    // Here is Background Thread, never alter adapter list in this method
    String charString = charSequence.toString();
    List<RegisterGuestList.Guest> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (charString.isEmpty()) {
        filteredList.addAll(mSearchGuestListResponseList);
    } else {
        ... // fill filteredList as you did previously
    }

    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
    filterResults.values = filteredList;
    filterResults.count = filteredList.size(); // count is optional
    return filterResults;
}

@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
    // Here is Main Thread, safe to update list and notify adapter
    mSearchGuestListResponseListFiltered = (ArrayList<RegisterGuestList.Guest>) filterResults.values;
    searchText = charSequence.toString();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

---

### 3. Use FilterListener to get notified when filter completed.

In your `onQueryTextChange()` of `SearchGuestActivity`, you want check adapter list size to show or hide a empty view. As Filter works in background thread you must perform filter call with a [FilterListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.FilterListener) to check empty list.

**Remove your `setFilter()` method of SearchGuestListAdapter and Fix `onQueryTextChange()` of SearchGuestActivity with the following structure:**

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    mSearchGuestListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText, new Filter.FilterListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
            if (count == 0) {
                // Show empty view...
            } else {
                // Show recyclerView...
            }
        }
    });

    // Don't call notifyDataSetChanged() or setFilter() here!
    // Adaper will notified by publishResults() method
    // mSearchGuestListAdapter.setFilter(newText);
    // mSearchGuestListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace above, seems like doesn't related on your code implicitly. And issue caused by internal RecyclerView implementation of animations. Also [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220771/recyclerview-inconsistency-detected-invalid-item-position).

**1)** Possible workarounds for it, just clearing active `ViewHolder`s pool, which could be pending on animation. And could throw `IndexOfBoundException`. Call below methods, before any `notifyDataSetChanged`.

```
mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**2)** Make sure you don't have `notifyItemRangeChanged` or `notifyItemAdded`(and similar) methods in your adapters. Use `notifyDataSetChanged`. Of course you can avoid this, but you need to use single collection and debug correct position every time to use this features.

**3)** And finally as you can see, it's all about animation for your items and internal behavior for `RecyclerView`. To resolve it from another side, you could override `LayoutManager` and remove animation. This will ensure, there is no issue with positions within your implementation.

```
/**
 * Could be the same for Grid LayoutManager or Linear
 **/
private static class NpaLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    /**
     * Disable predictive animations. There is a bug in RecyclerView which causes views that
     * are being reloaded to pull invalid ViewHolders from the internal recycler stack if the
     * adapter size has decreased since the ViewHolder was recycled.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
        return false;
    }
// .....
}
```

Comment: Is there anything for a linearlayoutmanager? how do i inject it into my code?

Comment: also, in my activity I do call :                 Objects.requireNonNull(mRecyclerView).getRecycledViewPool().clear();
 every single time i call notifydatasetchanged. I do not use notifyItemRangeChanged or itemadded. I do setitemanimator to null while setting adapter in activity. tried all solutions including that link, no luck so far :(

Comment: @AngelaHeely Check the answer. As I mentioned it could be done for any `LayoutManager`.

Comment: @AngelaHeely Did you have chance to try it?

Comment: i did, still crashes for me. not sure whats missing :(

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 11(offset:11).state:26 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{8f5265 VFED.V... ......ID 0,0-1080,4914 #7f090216 app:id/search_guests_recycler_view}, adapter:com.myapp.ui.registervisitor.searchGuests.SearchGuestListAdapter@73f0b3a, layout:com.myapp.utils.NpaLinearLayoutManager@41fa3eb, context:com.myapp.ui.registervisitor.searchGuests.SearchGuestActivity@f789333

Answer (score 0):

Replace all occurrences of `mSearchGuestListResponseList`

in `SearchGuestListAdapter#getItemCount()`,

and in `SearchGuestListAdapter#getItemViewType()`

with `mSearchGuestListResponseListFiltered`;

Comment: do you happen to have any ides about this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58629974/how-do-i-fix-crash-with-java-lang-string-android-net-uri-getscheme-for-ics-pa

Comment: @AngelaHeely the link is dead

Comment: sorry, here's the other link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58632013/ics-file-is-not-parsing-and-retrieving-data-as-expected-in-android-using-ical

Comment: do you also happen to know if there's any sample app that displays a timeline for the date on calendar, in minutes and you can select a slot to book or save an event?

Comment: any idea about this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58848391/how-do-i-synchronize-scrollview-positions-of-dynamic-horizontal-scroll-views-ins